# Databinding on an ObservableCollection made from 2 ObservableCollection in C# WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, observablecollection

I got some issues while trying to bind an ObservableCollection made from 2 others. 
First I need to bind ActiveSketchs, Second i have to bind Sketchs (Which is ActivesSketchs.Union(InactiveSketchs) separately.

I thought the code below would work but it doesn't. The ActiveSketch binding works correctly, but not the Sketchs one :

```
    private ObservableCollection<Sketch> _sketchs;
    public ObservableCollection<Sketch> Sketchs
    {
        get { return _sketchs = new ObservableCollection<Sketch>(ActiveSketchs.Union(InactiveSketchs)); }
        set { _sketchs = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Sketch> _activeSketchs;
    public ObservableCollection<Sketch> ActiveSketchs
    {
        get { return _activeSketchs; }
        set { _activeSketchs = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Sketch> _inactiveSketchs;
    public ObservableCollection<Sketch> InactiveSketchs
    {
        get { return _inactiveSketchs; }
        set { _inactiveSketchs = value; }
    }
```

And here's how i set the source item :

```
    HeadbandRight.ItemsSource = Sketchs;
    HeadbandLeft.ItemsSource = Sketchs;
    MainScatterViewer.ItemsSource = ActiveSketchs;
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Please note that `Sketchs` will always be a new instance whenever you request it. That's a bad idea. Instead listen for changes in `ActiveSketchs` and `InactiveSketchs` and update `Sketchs` accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting 0 error, it's just that the "Sketchs" container is still void. Afterwards that was stupid from me to make a new instance for Sketchs... I will investigate how to update Sketch according to Active/InactiveSketchs changing, thanks !

Comment: You should instantiate from within the constructor, not the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) to get filtered items from your list :

```
public InitFunction()
{
    this.Sketchs = new ObservableCollection<Sketch>();

    this.ActiveSketchs = new CollectionViewSource();
    this.ActiveSketchs.Source = this.Sketches ;
    this.ActiveSketchs.Filter += (s, e) =>
    {
        var sketch = e.Item as Sketch;

        e.Accepted = sketch.IsActive; // or whatever test you need
    };

    HeadbandRight.ItemsSource = Sketchs;
    HeadbandLeft.ItemsSource = Sketchs;
    MainScatterViewer.ItemsSource = ActiveSketchs.View;
}

public ObservableCollection<Sketch> Sketchs { get; set; }

public CollectionViewSource ActiveSketchs { get; set; }
```

Full example here : http://uicraftsman.com/blog/2010/10/27/filtering-data-using-collectionviewsource/

Answer (score 0):

This just does not make sense to me

```
private ObservableCollection<Sketch> _sketchs;
public ObservableCollection<Sketch> Sketchs
{
    get { return _sketchs = new ObservableCollection<Sketch>(ActiveSketchs.Union(InactiveSketchs)); }
    set { _sketchs = value; }
}
```

Why have a set if the get is a union?

If it just has a get why does it need to be an ObservableCollection?
A change to the individual OCs are not going to fire a collection changed on the combined anyway.
You can return a combined OC by newing but a change to oc1 or oc2 is still not going to fire a collection changed OCcomb for the UI to know to update.
Since you need to manually fire a NotifyPropertyChanged on the combined you might as well return an IEnumerable.

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> oc1 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ObservableCollection<string> oc2 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        oc1.Add("one");
        oc1.Add("two");
        oc2.Add("three");
        oc2.Add("four");
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> IEcomb { get { return oc1.Union(oc2); } }
    public ObservableCollection<string> OCcomb { get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(oc1.Union(oc2)); } }
```

Comment: Doesn't working, like Daniel Hilgarth said : "Please note that Sketchs will always be a new instance whenever you request it. That's a bad idea. Instead listen for changes in ActiveSketchs and InactiveSketchs and update Sketchs accordingly."

Comment: Did you try the Or: which does NOT create a new?

Comment: Unions() return an IEnumerable, and the only way I know to convert an IEnumerable to an ObservableCollection is to make a new ObservableCollection right?

Comment: If it only has a get then why does it need to be an ObservableCollection?  See my tested answer.

Comment: It need to be an ObservableCollection otherwise I get an error.

Comment: Could you show the line that throw the error?  And I will add some options to the answer.

Comment: The error was: "Cannot implicitly convert type system.collection.generic.ienumerable into Observable Collection ". For your updated answer it doesn't work because i need an ObservableCollection otherwise the WPF elements aren't updated (Tested it)

Comment: But as I stated in the answer.  A change to the individual OCs are not going to fire a collection changed on the combined anyway.   You can return an OC by newing but that is still not going to update the UI.